# Creating a loop/function from scraped data in rvest

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rvest, stringr

So I've created this script which accomplishes what I want to do on each individual page:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/ohio-state/Season/2022-Football/Targets/")
page <- read_html(targets_url)

jsons <- page %>%   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@type ="application/ld+json"]') 
allplayers <- jsonlite::fromJSON( html_text(jsons[2]))

list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()
nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))

answer2 <- cbind(rep(category, nrepeats), allplayers$athlete)
answer2$target_category <- answer2$`rep(category, nrepeats)`

target_df <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle)
```

But as you can see, there's a hard coded URL in there `ohio-state`

What if I wanted to automate this with multiple iterations? Let's say the first couples lines on the script was:

```
teams <- c("ohio-state","penn-state","michigan","michigan-state")
```

So my end result was an aggregate dataframe with the results from those four URLs? Also, I want to tack on a fourth column on `target_df` based on the `teams` list, so it would look something like this:

```
target_df <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle) %>% mutate(team = teams[1])
```

Obviously it wouldn't remain `teams[1]` in the larger script, but just giving what I would want for that fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use a for loop for this.  Someone will be along with other solutions.

```
teams <- c("ohio-state","penn-state","michigan","michigan-state")
for (team in teams) {
targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/",team,"/Season/2022-Football/Targets/")
page <- read_html(targets_url)

jsons <- page %>%   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@type ="application/ld+json"]') 
allplayers <- jsonlite::fromJSON( html_text(jsons[2]))

list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()
nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))

answer2 <- cbind(rep(category, nrepeats), allplayers$athlete, team)
answer2$target_category <- answer2$`rep(category, nrepeats)`

target_df <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle)
}
```

I think...

Comment: Thank you, this works, but one question: What if I wanted to put in that final `teams` column. I tried doing `target_df <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle) %>% mutate(team = teams[1:T])` but that only populated it with the first item on the list (`ohio-state`)

Comment: Oh, also.... now that I check, it looks like it's only returning one of the datasets. The final count should be 930.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's only returning the values from the final item on the list

Comment: Ah. This is the trouble with coding on my phone and not testing it.

Comment: No worries, good effort. If you want to try fixing it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
teams <- c("ohio-state","penn-state","michigan","michigan-state")
for (team in teams) {
targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/",team,"/Season/2022-Football/Targets/")
page <- read_html(targets_url)

jsons <- page %>%   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@type ="application/ld+json"]') 
allplayers <- jsonlite::fromJSON( html_text(jsons[2]))

list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()
nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))

answer2 <- cbind(rep(category, nrepeats), allplayers$athlete, team)
answer2$target_category <- answer2$`rep(category, nrepeats)`

if (exists("target_df")) {
target <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle)

target_df <- rbind( target_df, target)

} else {

target_df <- answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle)
}
}
```

Does this one work?
And is team not being added now in the answer2<- cbind line?

Comment: If this is your revised code, then please delete your original answer or edit your other answer. It is ver confusing to have two very similar answers from the same person.

Comment: No. `Error in exists(target_df) : invalid first argument`

Comment: Dave2e - if the answer is to simply provide complete off the shelf answers, I agree. But actually, while there is a conversation taking place, I think it helps the poster understand the change and learn to code rather than just copy code.

Comment: Sorry target_df needs to be in quotes. That always catches me out.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that you want to extract from each page in a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_data <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  jsons <- page %>%   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@type ="application/ld+json"]') 
  allplayers <- jsonlite::fromJSON( html_text(jsons[2]))
  
  list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
  headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
  category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()
  nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))
  
  answer2 <- cbind(rep(category, nrepeats), allplayers$athlete)
  answer2$target_category <- answer2$`rep(category, nrepeats)`
  
  answer2 %>% select(target_category, name, jobTitle)
}
```

Create links to extract data from

```
teams <- c("ohio-state","penn-state","michigan","michigan-state") 
urls <- sprintf('https://247sports.com/college/%s/Season/2022-Football/Targets/', teams)
```

Use `map_df` to get data from each link and combine them into one dataframe with a `team` column that will identify from which team the data is from.

```
map_df(urls, get_data, .id = 'team') %>%  
    mutate(team = teams[as.integer(team)]) -> result
result
```

Comment: This appears to just take the object in the list `ohio-state` and multiplying everything by four. The end amount should be 930.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the function. It should read `page <- read_html(url)`. I have updated the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you, king.

Comment: One of the solutions (function or loop) will be a better solution. The two deciding factors would be speed and stability. Stability would be my bigger concern - web scraping always risks a 404 or just a network outage. I don't know which is best, and it may vary between use cases.